# how can minimize timing in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using following news ticker plugins to scroll my news in the web site.

```
 var $mask = $strip.wrap("<div class='mask'></div>");
 var $tickercontainer = $strip.parent().wrap("<div class='tickercontainer'></div>");
 var containerHeight = $strip.parent().parent().height();    //a.k.a. 'mask' width
 $strip.height(stripHeight);
 var defTiming = totalTravel/settings.travelocity;   // thanks to Scott Waye
 function scrollnews(spazio, tempo){
   $strip.animate({top: '-'+ spazio}, tempo, "linear", function(){
     $strip.css("top", containerHeight); 
     scrollnews(totalTravel, defTiming);
    });
 }

 scrollnews(totalTravel, defTiming);
 $strip.hover(function(){
   jQuery(this).stop();
 }, function(){
   var offset = jQuery(this).offset();
   var residualSpace = offset.top + stripHeight;
   var residualTime = residualSpace/settings.travelocity;
   scrollnews(residualSpace, residualTime);
 });
 });
 };

 $(function(){
   $("ul#ticker01").liScroll();
 });
```

now I need minimize the speed of the scrolling. how can do this?

Comment: Are you using any plugin for this ?

Comment: not any pluging

Comment: Then what is `settings.travelocity` ?

Comment: @Lilan do you want to consider in using a plugin?

Comment: any way I need minimize the scrolling speed?

Comment: Change settings.travelocity to make it faster or slower...